# keydown event not working when other function code present

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok, I'm really really stumped here. I am binding a function to keydown, but it will not fire off if a particular condition is present in two seemingly unrelated pieces of code.

html

```
<input id="enteredData" name="enteredData" />
<button id="submit-button">Submit</button>
```

keydown function:

```
$(document).on("keydown", function(e) {
    console.log("keydown")
    if (!$("#enteredData").is(":focus")) {
        $("#enteredData").focus();
    }
});
```

here are the other seemingly unrelated pieces of code

```
$(function() {
    $("#submit-button").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("submit")
        if (!$("#enteredData").is(":disabled") {    
            // do something 
        }
    });
});

function onAction(data) {
    if (!$("#enteredData").is(":disabled") {        
        // do something 
    }
}
```

see the common if statement in them? `if (!$("#enteredData").is(":disabled")`. If I remove that if condition from BOTH chunks of code, then the keydown function works fine. Really lost here.

Comment: Please update your question with a **runnable** [mcve] using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button) demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Feel free to check the console for javascript errors.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I made changes, is that better?

Comment: @James no errors in the console for some weird reason, but you can see Ben's answer for the culprit

Comment: Not really. Again, please create a **runnable** [mcve] using Stack Snippets that demonstrates the problem. What's in the question isn't runnable.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I've seen plenty of questions on SO that include html and js snippets without explicitly creating the whole document and script includes that assume valid html, custom js/jquery loading, etc. Is that what you're talking about?

Comment: @zero01alpha: I didn't say anything about "the whole document," I said a **minimal** complete example demonstrating the problem. And again: With Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Because the unrelated code has nothing to do with the problem code, so to figure it out, we're typically going to have to see the problem, live in front of us. I'm glad that someone spotted the typo for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be missing closing brackets on both of the `if` statements in your second code block.

```
$(function() {
    $("#submit-button").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("submit")
        if (!$("#enteredData").is(":disabled")) {
            processData($("#enteredData").val());           
        }
    });
});

function onAction(data) {
    if (!$("#enteredData").is(":disabled")) {       
        processData(data);
    }
}
```

Comment: @zero01alpha: It would, and does, on all major desktop browsers. (Probably most minor ones, too.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder wow....I just discovered that I somehow accidentally turned off JS in the Firefox console....the console.log statements were still showing though which is weird...jeez.